# Load product attribute in module block without using load() methos

Tags: magento-1.7

I've file like `app/code/local/Xx/Multistepcheckout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`

In which I've function like following

```
public function checkItemStatus($_item, $qty, $sku) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        $stockstatus = $_product->getXxxstatus();
        //Rest of the code....
}
```

Here in function I don't want to use following lines

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
```

**Try 1 :**
So to do so I've add following code in config.xml

```
<global>
       <sales>
            <quote>
                <item>
                    <product_attributes>
                        <xxxstatus />
                    </product_attributes>
                </item>
            </quote>
        </sales>
    </global>
```

And in this file `app/code/local/Xx/Multistepcheckout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php`
I've used like `$_item->getData('xxxstatus'))` but it's not working.

So is there any way in which I can reduce the use of `load()` method?

Let me know if you want more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways I've sorted using following..

```
$_item->getProduct()->getData('attributecode');
```

in function `checkItemStatus($_item, $qty, $sku)` .

Thanks.